# Classes on optgroup in yii 1

Tags: yii, dropdown

Is it possible to create a drop-down in yii 1 where optgroups have classes? 
I want to use $form->dropDownList()

eg:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars" class="swedish">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars" class="german">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: where is your code mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) and source code and there is nothing implemented to set the class, or any other attribute for the `<optgroup>` tag (see here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.19/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L2547).

The only way I can see for you to achieve this is to implement your own class, extending `CHtml`, and override the function `listOptions()` with your own implementation. That could then handle any additional options for optgroup classes as you wish.

Note that with this approach you then can't use `$form->dropDownList()` but would have to use `YourNewClass::activeDropDownList()` instead.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep that would be one option.